# Is it legal to repeat the same value in a MULTIPLECHARVALUE or MULTIPLESTRINGVALUE field?

Tags: fix-protocol

Let's assume a FIX field is of type `MULTIPLECHARVALUE` or `MULTIPLESTRINGVALUE`, and the enumerated values defined for the field are `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. I know that `"A C D"` is a legal value for this field, but is it legal for a value to be repeated in the field? For example, is `"A C C D"` legal? If so, what are its semantics?

I can think of three possibilities:

1. `"A C C D"` is an invalid value because `C` is repeated.
2. `"A C C D"` is valid and semantically the same as `"A C D"`. In other words, *set* semantics are intended.
3. `"A C C D"` is valid and has [*multiset/bag*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)#Multiset) semantics.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any clear definition of the intended semantics of `MULTIPLECHARVALUE` and `MULTIPLESTRINGVALUE` in FIX specification documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FIX50SP2 spec does not answer your question, so I can only conclude that any of the three interpretations could be considered valid.

Like so may questions with FIX, the true answer is dependent upon the counterparty you are communicating with.

So my answer is:

1. if you are client app, ask your counterparty what they want (or check their docs).
2. if you are the server app, you get to decide.  Your docs should tell your clients how to act.

If it helps, the QuickFIX/n engine treats MultipleCharValue/MultipleStringValue fields as strings, and leaves it to the application code to parse out the individual values.  Thus, it's easy for a developer to support any of the interpretations, or even different interpretations for different fields.  (I suspect the other QuickFIX language implementations are the same.)

Answer (score 1):

The definition of `MultipleValueString` field is a string field containing one or more space delimited values. I haven't got the official spec, but there are few locations where this definition can be found:

1. https://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/4.2/index.html#MultipleValueString (I know onixs.biz to be very faithful to the standard specification)

   > String field (see definition of "String" above) containing one or more space delimited values.
2. https://aj-sometechnicalitiesoflife.blogspot.com/2010/04/fix-protocol-interview-questions.html

   > **12. What is MultipleValueString data type? [...]**
   > String field containing one or more space delimited values.

This leaves it up to a specific field of this type whether multiples are allowed or not, though I suspect only a few if any would *need* to have multiples allowed. As far as I can tell, the FIX specification deliberately leaves this open.

E.g. for [ExecInst<18>](https://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/4.2/tagNum_18.html) it would be silly to specify the same instruction multiple times. I would also suspect each and every implementation to behave differently (for instance one ignoring duplicates, another balking with an error/rejection).